# JQUERY scroller content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, customization

I have a page with content that came from my database, but I want to be able to show that content like this http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/244/Amazon-style-image-and-title-scroller-with-jQuery I've downloaded the script and I did (I think) like the tutorial, but it's not working at all. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I don't know what.

```
<link href="css/amazon_scroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/amazon_scroller.js"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#amazon_scroller").amazon_scroller({
                scroller_title_show: 'enable',
                scroller_time_interval: '0',
                scroller_window_background_color: "#CCC",
                scroller_window_padding: '10',
                scroller_border_size: '1',
                scroller_border_color: '#000',
                scroller_images_width: '150',
                scroller_images_height: '100',
                scroller_title_size: '12',
                scroller_title_color: 'black',
                scroller_show_count: '2',
                directory: 'images'
            });
        });
    </script>

<div id="amazon_scroller1" class="amazon_scroller">

<div class="amazon_scroller">
        <div class="amazon_scroller_mask">
            <ul>

 <li>
<?php do { ?>

<div align="center" id="thumb"><a href="legendofgames/gameview.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_GameData['idGames']; ?>"><img src="../legendofgames/documentos/games/<?php echo $row_GameData['strImage']; ?>" width="165" height="120"/></a>
<div align="center" id="gametext"><?php echo $row_GameData['strNome']; ?> </div>
</div> 


<?php } while ($row_GameData = mysql_fetch_assoc($GameData)); ?>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="amazon_scroller_nav">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code put each item (link + image) in a `<li>` while your code puts all item in the same `<li>`. Try:

```
<div id="amazon_scroller1" class="amazon_scroller">

<div class="amazon_scrolle  r">
<div class="amazon_scroller_mask">

<ul>
<?php do { ?>
<li>
<div align="center" id="thumb"><a href="legendofgames/gameview.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_GameData['idGames']; ?>"><img src="../legendofgames/documentos/games/<?php echo $row_GameData['strImage']; ?>" width="165" height="120"/></a>
<div align="center" id="gametext"><?php echo $row_GameData['strNome']; ?> </div>
</div>
</li>
<?php } while ($row_GameData = mysql_fetch_assoc($GameData)); ?>



</ul>
</div>
</div>
        <ul class="amazon_scroller_nav">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and I notice that there is no css script such as #amazon_scroller1